# com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException in WAS with spring 3.1.1

Tags: java, websphere-8, java-6, spring-web

I am getting this exception with Websphere 8 + spring 3.1.1 + java 1.6.

I am not using AOP in my code and spring bean cong xml is also clean and basic just to initialize spring web context and view resolver for jsp. Please any comment...

com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: For method, org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.releaseBean[com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@932034201 ( org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.releaseBean )], parameters were specified, but null was the expected comparison